# Why is Jackson mapping these values twice, in differing case?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm mapping a Java object to JSON using Jackson, the object is a pretty simple pojo class that looks like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonAutoDetect
public class Area {
    @JsonProperty("Id")
    public int Id;
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    public String Name;

    public Area() {
        Name = "";
    }

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }
}
```

The mapping code then looks like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

mapper.setVisibilityChecker(mapper.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
            .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
            .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));

areaJSON = mapper.writeValueAsString(area);
```

But the value of areaJSON at this point is then as follows:

```
{"id":0,"name":"","Name":"","Id":0}
```

Note the multiple values with differing case.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Good question. Thank you for providing an accurate [MVCE!](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Jackson thinks that the fields `Id` and `Name` are different properties from the ones returned by the getters because the case is different. Using standard JavaBeans naming conventions, Jackson infers the fields corresponding to the getters are named `id` and `name`, not `Id` and `Name`.

tl;dr case matters.

---

There are two simple ways to fix this problem:

1. Remove the `@JsonAutoDetect` annotation from this class entirely. I'm pretty sure that the default annotation values are taking precedence over the `ObjectMapper`'s configuration. Alternately:
2. Don't muck with the `ObjectMapper` at all. Change the `@JsonAutoDetect` on the class to

   ```
   @JsonAutoDetect(
     fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY,
     getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE,
     setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE,
     creatorVisibility = Visibility.NONE
   )
   ```

Comment: I agree of course that case is important, but shouldn't jackson ignore the getters and setters of the pojo due to the setter/getter visibility options set? Also worth mentioning that my hands are tied in terms of variable name due to other dependencies.

Comment: Why are your fields public? And why do they use unconventional casing? Field names in Java should be lowerCamelCased.

Comment: It's a long story that I could probably fix with enough time, but not really relevant to the problem at hand. I agree wholeheartedly that the naming should follow the conventions, though.

Comment: Looks good! I'll accept as soon as the timer is up. Worth mentioning that in the untested example fieldVisibility isn't found but the rest works perfectly. (And of course I don't need fieldVisibility changed anyway).

Comment: Fixed. Just had a typo.

Answer (score 3):

You need to annotate getId method with @JsonProperty("Id"), otherwise getId will also be added with lowercase id.

Answer (score 1):

I know that it's an old post, but there is a simpler solution:
use only annotation on fields:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Area {
   public int id;
   public String name;

   public Area() {
     name = "";
   }

   public int getId() {
    return id;
   }

   public void setId(int id) {
     id = id;
   }

   public String getName() {
     return name;
   }

   public void setName(String Name) {
     this.name = Name;
   }
}
```

You can choose how to serialize the object: using the field or using the properties. If you use the fields, the getter and setter are ignored.

The problem in the code is created by the **first letter uppercase** : accessing the field, the json property is Id; accessing the getter , getId became id (first letter after get is coded in lower case).

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to move annotations to either setters or getters (either one is fine)